# Use a set of Responses for an OpenAPI ref

Tags: openapi

I have a set of endpoints and operations that can all return the same set of responses, for example:

```
# Installation Operations
/api/maint/locations/{locationID}:
  parameters:
    - $ref: '#/components/parameters/LocationID'
  post:
    operationId: installComponent
    tags:
      - Installation Operations
    description: |
      Attempts to 'install' the component at the given locationID.
      If no component is installed in the specified location and the componentID refers to a valid component, returns code 200.
      Otherwise, a 404 response will be issued in the case of a valid locationID, or 400 if the locationID is invalid.
    parameters:
      - $ref: '#/components/parameters/ComponentIDQuery'
    responses:
      200:
        $ref: '#/components/responses/SuccessResponse'
      400:
        $ref: '#/components/responses/BadRequestResponse'
      404:
        $ref: '#/components/responses/NoComponentResponse'
      default:
        $ref: '#/components/responses/UnknownErrorResponse'
  put:
    operationId: refreshInstalledComponent
    tags:
      - Installation Operations
    description: Adds 'removed_on' and 'installed_on' values for the currently install component at the specified locationID.
    responses:
      200:
        $ref: '#/components/responses/SuccessResponse'
      400:
        $ref: '#/components/responses/BadRequestResponse'
      404:
        $ref: '#/components/responses/NoComponentResponse'
      default:
        $ref: '#/components/responses/UnknownErrorResponse'
  delete:
    operationId: uninstallComponent
    tags:
      - Installation Operations
    description: |
      Attempts to 'uninstall' the component at the given locationID.
      If a component was installed in the specified locationID before this endpoint is called, then the removed component is returned.
      Otherwise, a 404 response will be issued in the case of a valid locationID, or 400 if the locationID is invalid.
    responses:
      200:
        $ref: '#/components/responses/ComponentResponse'
      400:
        $ref: '#/components/responses/BadRequestResponse'
      404:
        $ref: '#/components/responses/NoComponentResponse'
      default:
        $ref: '#/components/responses/UnknownErrorResponse'
```

(actually above, the `delete` returns a different code 200 response, but I could modify it to return the `SuccessResponse`, or not include it in the desired group.)

Here each of the responses is the same ~10 lines, pasted in a few places. Other sets of operations have similar patterns.

I'd like to be able to define something like:

```
# Installation Operations
/api/maint/locations/{locationID}:
  parameters:
    - $ref: '#/components/parameters/LocationID'
  post:
    operationId: installComponent
    tags:
      - Installation Operations
    description: |
      Attempts to 'install' the component at the given locationID.
      If no component is installed in the specified location and the componentID refers to a valid component, returns code 200.
      Otherwise, a 404 response will be issued in the case of a valid locationID, or 400 if the locationID is invalid.
    parameters:
      - $ref: '#/components/parameters/ComponentIDQuery'
    responses:
      $ref: '#/components/responses/LocationInstallationResponsesGroup'

responses:
  LocationInstallationResponsesGroup:
    - 200:
      $ref: '#/components/responses/ComponentResponse'
      description: Some other description
    - 400:
      $ref: '#/components/responses/BadRequestResponse'
    - 404:
      $ref: '#/components/responses/NoComponentResponse'
    - default:
      $ref: '#/components/responses/UnknownErrorResponse'
```

Is this possible using OpenAPI v3.0 (or 3.1?). If not, is there a better method to avoid the copy-pasting?

I also tried with `oneOf` for the `LocationInstallationResponsesGroup`, but couldn't figure out a way to make that work either.

Answer (score 1):

This is not supported.

Here's an existing feature request in the OpenAPI Specification repository:
[Add default responses](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/563)

Comment: Is [Group multiple parameter definitions for better maintainability](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/445) maybe a better fit? That issue describes parameter sets, but I think (maybe wrongly) that the goal is closer to this question. Conversely, the default responses issue looks like it's setting global responses to *all* paths that don't override it, with no ref but instead just the key?

Comment: It's similar but also different because a) it's about parameters specifically and doesn't mention other components; b) `responses` is a map whereas `parameters` is an array, so the syntax for group reuse (if it's ever implemented) would probably be different. You can always create a new feature request if the existing ones don't quite cover what you need.